# Tablayout set width

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

hi i have to developed one tab bar app.here 5 tabs are created.**The first tab width is larger than second and third tab width**.how can i do this????
please help me.
[image: current output]

wish to need the output like this:

[image: wish to need the output]

Here the dashboard tab is have to set the width is more larger than orders and customers.how can i do design and develop this.please help me.also how can i set the dashboard test color and style.please give me some solutions.i have searched google.more tutorial is best for me.so please give me some valuable solution for this.

Comment: Are these actionbar tabs? getActionBar().addTab() ?

Comment: i have used getActionBar().addTab();

Comment: i have worked from this tutorial:http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: if you have used linear layout as base for the tabs then you can specify weight property to each of the tabs
that will help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement custom tab indicator. You can refer to this [link](http://ondrejcermak.info/en/programovani/custom-tabs-in-android-tutorial/) for help. Still facing any problem then tell me I will help you out.

Comment: ya its very useful link....but here i wish to set the first tab width is larger than second and third tab width.so its not helpful for me.because my first tab have to display DashBoard fully.in my code d is missing.in your code also gave dashBoa ly displayed.check it dis screenshot:http://screencast.com/t/QE2feiHeTI4x           so please give me solution for set the width for first tab